# Applet with jMonkeyEngine?

Tags: eclipse, applet, jmonkeyengine

I want to host a jMonkeyEngine game as an applet, but I can't figure out how. [These instructions](http://www.jarplus.com/JME-Java_Monkey_Engine-Doc/JMonkeyDocumentationChapter1.pdf) recommend having the main class inherit from `SimpleJMEApplet`, but Eclipse complains that it can't find the class.

Any other documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but since there's no answer...

I managed to deploy an applet with the official IDE and not using SimpleJMEApplet but just extending SimpleApplication.

In the official IDE, right-click your project : properties
                Application - Applet : check "Create Applet"
                Then, click on "Clean and Build"

In your project folder you'll find a "dist" folder containing an "Applet" folder.

Only code.jar and data.jar depend on your code, other archives must be replaced.

To replace the archives, you need to go look for the last version of lwjgl_applet. 
I don't know if lwjgl 3 supports this, but you can find the last lwjgl_applet [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%202.9.3/)

There are two folders, "basic" and "advanced". The method I used needs the "basic" jars.

You need to use jarsigner (which is stored in a JDK) to sign all the basic jar with a key of your own. There also is a html file which is the entry point to your applet.

Once you've signed all the lwjgl_applet jars with your own key you can add code.jar and data.jar in the same folder and then sign them with your key.

You should now be able to launch your applet from a browser. Beware of warning security risks etc.